# Is creating a custom animation class for controlling animations a good practice?

Tags: android, android-animation

```
Android studio 3.4.1
```

Creating a custom animation class for controlling animations

I have the following interface for starting, stopping, and checking if the animation is running

```
interface AnimationController {
    fun start()
    fun isRunning(): Boolean
    fun stop()
}
```

The implemetation

```
class AnimationControllerImp : AnimationController {

    private companion object {
        const val START_DELAY = 500L
        const val DURATION = 400L
    }

    private val animationSet by lazy {
        AnimatorSet()
    }

    override fun isRunning() = animationSet.isRunning

    override fun stop() {
        animationSet.end()
    }

    override fun start() {
        val textAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluatorCompat(), 0, 1)
        textAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            /* do some animation here */
        }

        val backgroundAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1)
        backgroundAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            /* do some animation here */
        }

        animationSet.startDelay = START_DELAY
        animationSet.duration = DURATION
        animationSet.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
        animationSet.playTogether(textAnimator, backgroundAnimator)
        animationSet.start()
        animationSet.addListener(object: Animator.AnimatorListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {

            }

            override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {

            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {

            }    
        })
    }
}
```

Then a client could use this class as follows

```
fun startPlayTogether() {
    val animationController: AnimationController = AnimationControllerImp()
    if(animationController.isRunning) {
        animationController.stop()    
    }
    else {
        animationController.start()
    }
}
```

Is this is a good design for a custom animation class?